# How to use the SQL LIKE operator on a python variable with a % wildcard using named paramstyle placeholder

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to do a wildcard search to find values that have the string of a variable in any position, so searching like %this%, but I just can't work out what to enclose in %%.  I've tried all kinds of combinations with single quotes and % in different places.

```
variable = request.form.get("input")
results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE :placeholder", {"placeholder": variable}).fetchall()
```

Comment: try this one `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE :placeholder || '%'", `

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
variable = request.form.get("input")
variable = f"%{variable}%"
results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE :placeholder", {"placeholder": variable}).fetchall()
```